# anarchist vs. anarchistic

Tags: adjectives

As an adjective, what is the adjectival use case for ["anarchist" vs. "anarchistic"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anarchist)? E.g., in

> The cynic Diogenes of Sinope and Crates of Thebes are both supposed to have advocated [for anarchist/anarchistic] forms of society, although little remains of their writings.

and also used in the construction "display anarchistic tendencies/traits."

Is there any reason to use one versus the other?

Comment: "Anarchist" is a noun, not an adjective, and in "an anarchist plot" it is a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

Comment: [MW lists both as adjectives](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anarchist)

Comment: As it happens, so does [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/anarchist).

Comment: I don't think there is a consistent use-case differentiating the two, save (maybe) whether the user needs to differentiate between something *for an anarchist* and something *with anarchistic qualities*.